# JavaScript Detect is Cyclic in an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, recursion

I have an array of Javascript objects as follows

```
a=[
  {id:1, parentId:2},
  {id:2, parentId:3},
  {id:3, parentId:4},
  {id:4, parentId:1},
  {id:5, parentId:5}
];
```

I would like to detect in this array
if any object refers to itself directly (5->5) or if refers to itself by other parents like 1->2->3->4->1

what is the best way to write it?

PS. There is another question like this one but it is not answered the question. the accepted answer is about a graph and it returns color coding,
[How to detect a loop in a hierarchy of javascript elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55338929/how-to-detect-a-loop-in-a-hierarchy-of-javascript-elements) but mine is parentId

my expected behaviour is:
**false, 5->5 and 1->2->3->4->1**
or simply false, neighter colour coding nor for graph :)

Comment: Why does it make a difference whether it's `parent` or `parentId`? The algorithm is the same.

Comment: Dear @Barmar thanks for your answer. The accepted answer is a graph with vortex
graph = [
    [2, 1],
    [3, 2],
    [1300023, 3],
    [1, 1300023],
];
and it is not an array of objects.
and return some colour coding array, I would like just to know if it is false or which id is incorrect

Comment: If this is homework, see: [How to ask homework question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions) and [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems)

Comment: Sorry, @Barmar if it looks like homework to you. anyway thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is non-recursive. Not most efficient, but checks items one by one - looking up the parent chain until found a match or no parent found. Then moving to next item.

Edit: Need of course to check against all items along the way of the chain (not just first) to prevent infinite loops in case of (1->2->2).

```js
var a = [
  {id:1, parentId:2},
  {id:2, parentId:2},
  {id:3, parentId:4},
  {id:4, parentId:7},
  {id:5, parentId:6}
];

function search_id(arr, id) {
  return arr.find(item => item.id === id)
}

function is_array_cyclic(arr) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var item = arr[i];
    var seen = [item.id]

    while (true) {
      var parent = search_id(arr, item.parentId);
      if (parent === undefined) {
        break;
      }
      if (seen.indexOf(parent.id)>-1) {
        // cyclical
        return true;
      }
      seen.push(parent.id);
      item = parent;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

console.log(is_array_cyclic(a))
```

Answer (score 1):

Your data *does* describe a [directed] graph. In fact, your model is for all intents and purposes an *adjacency list* describing this :

[image]

Any graph traversal algorithm that tracks visited nodes can detect cycles in the graph:

- https://fireship.io/courses/javascript/interview-graphs/
- https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-graph-javascript/

I might suggest converting your list of `{id, parentId}` tuples into a map, where the keys are the `id` properties, and the value is the associated `parentId` (or a list of associated `parentID` properties, in case the same node can have has multiple parents).

Comment: Thanks Nicholas, appreciate it